# Downloading partial data from Kaggle

Tags: kaggle

I am working on a project that identifies chess positions. The main database I found is on Kaggle however is it's size is 2 GB. Does anyone know if I can download only a small portion of the set instead of the entire thing?
link: https://www.kaggle.com/koryakinp/chess-positions

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it by clicking on the file one by one and click the download button on the top right of the file.

[image]
One more way you can do it download everything and delete the files you dont want.

Or you can use wget in command prompt or curl in terminal and use `--max-filesize` to limit it to the amount of bites you want.